# jQuery datepicker when loaded says undefined.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to implement a date picker in my form however when the code it added the date picker does not display in the brewers. When the console is inspected this error is posted
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()')
The jQuery library file is added in the root folder.

Bellow is the code used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the datepicker () call inside the head tag after the necessary includes are made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your jQuery code after including `jQuery` and `datepicker` core file:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The jQuery code is in a separate file, however I just tried that way and it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add the jquery-ui.js after the jquery-1.10.2.js entry.

Try placing the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

at the end of the file after the html tag and around a script tag e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following code in VS2012 and it works.  You will need to changed the version numbers here to your own.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the scripts pointing to the correct location in your workspace.

Try putting the jQuery's document.ready function inside the head tag after the necessary includes are made.

I guess by markup, script tags are to be placed either inside the body tag or the head tag

Hope this works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

This perfectly works.

jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumars08/98CRq/

HTML:

```
<p>
Date: 
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  What I did to fix it was to add a reference to the scripts after the control.

```html
<head>
  <link href="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type='text' onkeypress='return false' class='datepicker' />
  </div>
  
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(this).ready(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the function that will invoke the datepicker for your input label.
put the js code at the end of the file.
also don´t forget to include this code this into a function that will execute itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
})();
</script>
```