# date picker undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

IM using the following code and I got error is the console
undifinnd is not a function,what am I doing wrong here ?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('#datetime').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

I've also try with and I got the same error...

```
$('#datetime')..datetimepicker();
```

Comment: you are trying to use a `jquery-ui` method, you need to include its library, refer to http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582585/jquery-datepicker-when-loaded-says-undefined
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462068/datepicker-undefined-is-not-a-function

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any search effort.  Before asking questions, you should look for it online.  You may also want to read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to make sure that the question fits all guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like from the code you are only inlcuding the main jQuery library and not including the jQueryUI library for which that method is part of (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). If you include the jqueryUI library after your jQuery script call you should stop getting errors.

Comment: how should I get this libarary ?should I add it to my scripts ?

Comment: I add the following and its not helped <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: you need to add both javascript library and theme css, there are tons of tutorials there

Comment: @G.Mendes - I added to my page the following and still i have eroor,any idea? <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   

<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: shouldn't have any issues http://jsfiddle.net/Z3zHP/ review your input `ID` and how you add the functionality, wrap in `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is in [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).  You must include that library as well.